# Regex in find - OS X

Tags: find, osx, regular-expression

I cannot figure out what's wrong with my regex, it seems to be working with `grep` but now with `find`. I'm trying to find all the files which follow the common expression in TV shows e.g. **S02E21**.

```
find -E . -name '.*[sS]{1}[0-9]{1,2}[\.]?[eE]{1}[0-9]{1,2}.*\.mkv'
```

I get no results with `find`, however if I use the same regex in combination with `ls|grep -E '....'`, the files are found as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-name` takes [wildcard patterns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13), not regexps and matches on the file name, not its full path. Use `-regex` (or `-iregex`) for regexp matching but beware it matches against the full path. Here, you could do:

```
LC_ALL=C find -E . -iregex '.*s[0-9]{1,2}\.?e[0-9]{1,2}[^/]*\.mkv'
```

Here, we're replacing the second `.*` with `[^/]*`, that is a sequence of non-/ characters to make sure the pattern before it matches on the file name and not any of the directory components.

By fixing the locale to C with [`LC_ALL=C`](/a/87763), we're making sure `.` matches any byte and `[^/]` any byte but the one for `/` as otherwise you could run into problems with file or directory names encoded in a different character set as your locale's. Fixing the locale to C also guarantees `e` only matches on `e` and `E` (and `s` on `s` and `S`) with `-iregex`.

Note that `[\.]` matches on backslash or dot. To match a dot, it's either `\.` or `[.]`. Also `x{1}` is the same as `x`, so I've removed those `{1}` for simplification.

Check [your man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) for details. Note that none of `-E`, `-regex` or `-iregex` are [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

It can be simplified to

```
LC_ALL=C find -E . -iregex '.*s[0-9]{1,2}\.?e[0-9][^/]*\.mkv'
```

As the second digit if any would also be matched by `[^/]` anyway.

The standard equivalent using wildcard patterns would look like:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[sS][0-9][0-9].[eE][0-9]*.mkv' \
             -o -name '*[sS][0-9].[eE][0-9]*.mkv' \
             -o -name '*[sS][0-9][0-9][eE][0-9]*.mkv' \
             -o -name '*[sS][0-9][eE][0-9]*.mkv'
```

wildcard patterns, contrary to extended regular expressions don't have an alternation operator nor the equivalent of `?` or `{n,p}`, so we need 4 patterns to cover all possibilities.

You could also use a shell with recursive globbing and advanced wildcard patterns like `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
ls -lrtd -- **/(#i)*s<->e<->*.mkv
```

- `**/` recursive search
- `(#i)` case insensitive matching
- `<->` any decimal number

Passing to `ls -lrtd` here to print a list with details, sorted by last modification time, though of course you can use any command.

Comment: What's the difference between wildcard patterns and regex? Also is there a way to regex the file __names only__ with `find`? Lastly, what's the part before `find`?

Comment: @user14492, check edit

Comment: @user14492 See also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 0):

`find dir -name` just supports shell file name glob characters as documented by  `man fnmatch`.

Some find implementations support non-standard extensions for regular expressions. Check your `find` man page.